# Setting a default time using Pikaday

Tags: javascript

I'm using Owen Meads fork of Pikaday, which includes time selection (can be found [here](https://github.com/owenmead/Pikaday)). Is there a way to set the default time for the `time-picker` using JavaScript?

Here is what I have so far:

```
 var timepicker = new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById('<%= datetimepicker.ClientID %>'),
            firstDay: 1,
            minDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
            maxDate: new Date(2100, 12, 31),
            yearRange: [2000, 2100],
            showTime: true,
            autoClose: true,
            timeLabel: "Time In Work: ",
            use24hour: true,
            incrementMinuteBy: 5,
            format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm',
            disableDayFn: function(date) {
                return moment().isBefore(moment(date), 'day');
            }
 });
```

If not, how may I get around something like this? I have never forked a project from Github before and I am unsure where to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `setDate` method.

```
timepiker.setDate()
```

**EDIT**

Like this:

```
var timepicker = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('<%= datetimepicker.ClientID %>'),
  firstDay: 1,
  minDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
  maxDate: new Date(2100, 12, 31),
  yearRange: [2000, 2100],
  showTime: true,
  autoClose: true,
  timeLabel: "Time In Work: ",
  use24hour: true,
  incrementMinuteBy: 5,
  format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm',
  disableDayFn: function(date) {
    return moment().isBefore(moment(date), 'day');
  }
});
timepicker.setDate(new Date('14-Sep-2017 09:00:00'));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, is this included within the <script> tags or somewhere else?

Comment: Hmm ....no. After instantiation `var timepicker = new Pikaday({... });` set the date to whatever you want to be the initial value.

Comment: My mistake, I was calling it wrong. But it still isn't working... `setDate: '14-Sep-2017 09:00'`

Comment: Nope. you have to literaly write after what you have up, this: `timepicker.setDate(new Date('14-Sep-2017 09:00:00'));`

Answer (score 1):

When I worked with Pikaday package in Vue.Js project I had to set default date to my date field in form. I tried many different versions of setting default date.  But they didn't work for me. Finally I found the solution for my situation. The solution was to set prop like `auto-default="autoDefault"` here `autoDefault` is equels to `true` to Pikaday component like this...

```
<vue-pikaday v-model='date' auto-default="autoDefault" :options="pikadayOptions" />

 data() {
    return {
       autoDefault : true,
       pikadayOptions: {
           format  : 'YYYY/MM/DD',
           minDate : moment().toDate(),
       },
   }
},
```